# Pushing the stack

Tags: assembly, mips

Is there a difference when I do

```
addi $sp, $sp, -20
```

or

```
add $sp, $sp -20
```

or

```
addiu $sp, $sp, -20
```

?
Is it a convention to use one over the other? Or are there actual difference in how the stack is being moved? My instructor does

```
add $sp, $sp, 20
```

but

```
addi $sp, $sp, -20
```

when releasing the call frame

Answer (score 3):

`add $sp, $sp, 20` does not correspond to an actual MIPS instruction, and will be converted to either `addi` or `addiu` by the assembler.

The only difference between `addi` and `addiu` is that `addiu` doesn't signal an exception in case of an integer overflow. The description for `addiu` in *MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set* says (emphasis mine):

> This instruction is appropriate for unsigned arithmetic, **such as address arithmetic**, or integer arithmetic
>   environments that ignore overflow